# How to pass the index of the cell in the tableview from one view controller to the next upon pressing a button?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

Every time I try to do the following, it passes on the index to the next view controller as being 0. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help? Thank you so much! Here is the relevant code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "a", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


    cell.useButton.tag = tagBaseValue + indexPath.row
    cell.useButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ListViewController.useButtonPressed(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func useButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDisplay", sender: self)
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIButton) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDisplay" {

        let nextVC = segue.destination as! NextVC

        nextVC.index = sender.tag

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare(for` is never called because the signature is wrong (the type of `sender` is `Any?`)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDisplay" {

        let nextVC = segue.destination as! NextVC
        nextVC.index = (sender as! UIButton).tag

    }
}
```

and the `IBAction` must be

```
@IBAction func useButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDisplay", sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: However, nextVC.index has to be a class property.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare for segue must be overridden, and in button action while sending sender, you are sending the self, which is pointing to viewcontroller itself, hence you are receiving the tag always as 0.

Make changes for prepare for segue, make sender as Any and do overrride it. And in your button action while calling performSegue do mention sender as sender(which is button) and not self(which is view controller).

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped me.